Fortigate 40F syslog over TCP not working, but UDP works
Trying to send syslog over TCP from Fortigate 40F does not work, but it works over UDP.
The config for the syslogd settings are:
config log syslogd setting
    set status enable
    set server "80.127.31.22"
    set mode reliable
    set facility syslog
end

I have opened the firewall to the VM that is recieving the logs. I have tried to do a basic TCP setup on my Palo Alto PA-440 and this works.
Does anyone know what is causing the issue?

Have you tried set mode legacy-reliable?
